# Why is the transfer function of this circuit first order, when it has two energy storage elements?

Tags: circuit-analysis, control-system

I have the following circuit (assuming an ideal opamp),

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNfuis.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which has a transfer function that looks something like $$ \frac{As + 1}{Bs + 1}$$ when you take the output to be the output of the opamp, and the input to be the node before R1 and C1.

Trying to find the order of this circuit, my first impression was that it is a first order circuit. It's got a transfer function where the denominator has one for the highest power of s, and the differential equation that will describe it will be first order. However, a should be equivalent definition of the order of a system is the number of independant energy storage components, of which this circuit has two.

I know that the transfer function is first order, but there are two seemingly independant energy storage devices in this circuit. So what gives? Is it that the two capacitors are not "independant"?

Comment: Welcome! Please mark input and output with names nodes. I can guess but I prefer not to.

Comment: Yes, I've edited to be more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> there are two seemingly independent energy storage devices in this circuit. So what gives?

They are independent but only one stores the state of the system. The op-amp virtual ground allows the output to be determined by the voltage on \$C_2\$, which holds the system state.

\$C_1\$, on the input side along with \$R_1\$, determines how the state is modified by the input.

In order for independent storage elements to determine the order of the system, each one must hold a state variable.

The standard state equations demonstrate this.

$$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$$and$$y=Cx$$

Here:
\$C=1\$, \$y=v_{out}\$, \$x=v_{C2}\$ (the state variable), \$Bu=\left[\begin{array}{c}
b_{1}\dot{v}_{in}\\
b_{0}v_{in}
\end{array}\right]\$

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, thank you very much! So it's not true that the order of the system is the same as the number of energy storage elements in every case then. This also makes sense because the voltage across C1 is just the input voltage anyway so it can't also be a system state.

Comment: I did not write equations but if you insert a small resistance in series with \$C_1\$, like an ESR, then it becomes a 2nd-order system.

Comment: @JadonClugston: It is true for passive systems, but not necessarily true for active systems.

Comment: @VerbalKint: Yes it becomes 2nd Order while retaining a zero as well.

Comment: Oui, of course, the zero is still there : )

Comment: @RussellH

Interesting, do you have anywhere I can read more about this. Most of the sources I've read or heard from very much conflate the energy storage elements and the order of the system to be the same, regardless whether they are active or passive. Or at least they don't mention anything about active vs passive. But here's a clear contradiction, pretty interesting.

Comment: @JadonClugston: We call capacitors and inductors, "storage elements". But if they can't do the job of storing (for whatever reason) then they cannot contribute to defining the order. They are no longer acting as storage elements. The op-amp in this case allows the voltage source to be placed across C1, but allowing the current to pass through the feedback network instead of returning to Vin. Passive circuits can't do that. I don't know of any resource material that emphasizes this point.

Answer (score 3):

The transfer function can be found using the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs without writing a line of algebra, just going through a few simple sketches. In this analysis, you must realize that the (-) pin is at a 0-V potential considering the virtual ground:

[image]

First, determine the gain \$H_0\$ at dc by opening all the capacitors. Then reduce the stimulus to zero and determine the time constants of the circuit. Once done, find an impedance condition which would *null* the response at \$V_{out}\$. Assemble the final transfer function in a compact form.

A quick Mathcad sheet tells us if we are ok or not by comparing the brute-force expression with the *low-entropy* version:

[image]

If you want to learn about this technique, I recommend you look at my [APEC 2016](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) seminar which smoothly introduces the method.

Comment: I already know the transfer function, I derived it myself using nodal analysis :). Cool method though!

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXUGSc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=0\space\text{V}\tag4$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-0}{\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathscr{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=-\frac{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V1 = 0;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I0 == I1 + I2, 0 == I1 + I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (Vi - V1)/R2, I3 == (V2 - V1)/R3}, {V2, I0, I1, I2, I3}]]

Out[1]={{V2 -> -(((R1 + R2) R3 Vi)/(R1 R2)), I0 -> (1/R1 + 1/R2) Vi, 
  I1 -> Vi/R1, I2 -> Vi/R2, I3 -> -(((R1 + R2) Vi)/(R1 R2))}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

So, applying this to your case we can see that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\frac{\text{v}_2\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}\\
\\
&=-\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4}+\text{R}_2\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_4}\cdot\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=-\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}_3\text{R}_1}\cdot\left(1+\text{sC}_4\text{R}_2\right)}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}_4\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}_3\text{R}_1}
\end{split}\tag7
\end{equation}

Notice that when \$\text{R}:=\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2\$, this simplifies to:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=-\frac{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}_4\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}_3\text{R}}\tag8$$

Comment: The circuit in your answer does not match the circuit that I see in the question. Perhaps something is amiss somewhere?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy look again. At the end of my answer I applied it to the question of the OP. First I derive the transfer function.

Comment: The schematic was edited by the OP after I gave my answer, at least according to my timeline.